# Can not include jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I run Jade and Backbone, rendering with `.html()`. All template files are loaded using RequireJS and the jade! directive (example, jade!/templates/test.jade). In test.jade I have a Jade include-statement,

```
include test2
```

test2.jade is placed under template. When trying this I get an error in the browser (tried in Chrome),

```
Uncaught Error: failed to require "fs"
```

Anyone recognizing this problem? I tried to implicitly load test2.jade using the jade! directive, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I think we need some more information here. What does your require config look like? What do the test2 and test jade files look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue with `require-jade` plugin, which it sounds like you're using.

It turns out that it doesn't support `extends` or `includes` in the templates.

Answer (score -1):

`fs` generally refers to the filesystem.

Make sure your `app.js` or `server.js` file (whatever your main Node entry point file is) includes a line like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

If it is included, make sure it is required before jade.

Comment: The error is occurring in the browser which means somehow the fs module is being required by browser running code.  Being that the fs module for node is native only (it can't be browserified without using something like `brfs`), this is not the answer to the problem.